# Continues get request on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

The script works fine on my localhost (local machine) but when I try it after uploading it to my remote server it keeps repeating request infinitely on button click.

Here is the code for the same:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.product-btn').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-action')=="add"){
              $.ajax({url: "/product/add/cart/" + $(this).data("id") + "/from_listing/1"});
                  $(this).attr('data-action','remove');
                  $(this).children('span').html('Remove from cart');
          }else{
            $.ajax({url: "/product/delete/id/" + $(this).data("id") + "/"});
                $(this).attr('data-action','add');
                $(this).children('span').html('Add to cart');
          }
        });
    });
</script>
<button class="product-btn btn btn-sm btn-inverse btn-embossed" data-action="add" data-id="16545"><span>Add to cart</span></button>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the provided code that would cause an infinite loop. Maybe try adding some `console.log` messages and a success and failure handler on your ajax post to see if you can catch anything odd

Comment: Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ? Are `success` callbacks for `$.ajax()` within another portion of `js` not included at Question ?

Comment: @zgood @guest271314 Is it possible that there might be a conflict with prototype.js ? I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined prototype.js:115` in my Console. How do I avoid the conflict as I need both jQuery and prototype.

Comment: @KevinS [Read this doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)